# how to index for specific fields of documents using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

My requirement is to store specific fields of document to index in elasticsearch.
Example:
My document is

```
{
  "name":"stev",
  "age":26,
  "salary":25000
}
```

This is my document but i don't want indexing total document.I want store only name field.
I created one index emp and write mapping like below

```
"person" : {
    "_all" : {"enabled" : false},
    "properties" : {
        "name" : {
            "type" : "string", "store" : "yes"
        }
    }
}
```

When see the index document

```
{

    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 2,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "test",
                "_id": "AU1_p0xAq8r9iH00jFB_",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": { }
            }
            ,
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "test",
                "_id": "AU1_lMDCq8r9iH00jFB-",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": { }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

name fields is not generated,Why?
any one help to me

Comment: In your mapping, the type is called `person` but in your results I see `"_type": "test"`. Something's not correct there. Please show us the command you're using to index your documents.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong from what you posted, but I can give you an example that works.

Elasticsearch will, by default, index whatever source documents you give it. Every time it sees a new document field, it will create a mapping field with sensible defaults, and it will index them by default as well. If you want to exclude fields, you can set `"index": "no"` and `"store": "no"` in the mapping for each field you want to exclude. If you want that behavior to be the default for every field, you can use the `"_default_"` property for specifying that fields not be stored (though I couldn't get it to work for not indexing).

You probably also will want to disable [`"_source"`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html), and use the [`"fields"`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html) parameter in your search queries.

Here is an example. The index definition looks like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "person": {
         "_all": {
            "enabled": false
         },
         "_source": {
            "enabled": false
         },
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "analyzed", 
               "store": "yes"
            },
            "age": {
                "type": "integer",
                "index": "no",
                "store": "no"
            },
            "salary": {
                "type": "integer",
                "index": "no",
                "store": "no"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then I can add a few documents with the [bulk api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html):

```
POST /test_index/person/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"name":"stev","age":26,"salary":25000}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"name":"bob","age":30,"salary":28000}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"name":"joe","age":27,"salary":35000}
```

Since I disabled `"_source"`, a simple query will return only ids:

```
POST /test_index/_search
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

But if I specify that I want the `"name"` field, I'll get it:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "fields": [
      "name"
   ]
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "name": [
                  "stev"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "name": [
                  "bob"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "name": [
                  "joe"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

You can prove to yourself that the other fields were not stored by running:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "fields": [
      "name", "age", "salary"
   ]
}
```

which will return the same result. I can also prove that the `"age"` field wasn't indexed by running this query, which would return a document if `"age"` had been indexed:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "fields": [
      "name", "age"
   ],
   "query": {
      "term": {
         "age": {
            "value": 27
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

Here is a bunch of code I used for playing around with this. I wanted to use a [`_default`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/default-mapping.html) mapping and/or field to handle this without having to specify the settings for each field. I was able to make it work in terms of not storing data, but each field was still indexed.

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/d84967923d6c0757dba5f44240f47257ba2fbe50

Comment: Thank u for giving answer o me.Still fields were  indexed. I don't want that one,is there any possibility to do his one.And 

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/d84967923d6c0757dba5f44240f47257ba2fbe50 this is not open.